# wix toolset compare version use wixvariables

Tags: installation, wix, compare, windows-installer, version

I want to using different UpgradeCode for each ProductVersion

I use batch script parameter and get ProductVersion

and I define variables in INstallerProperties.wxi file below

`<?define ProductVersion="!(wix.ProductVersion)"?>`

I checked the value like 2.0.0.0

and I want to compare version for UpgradeCode like the code below.

```
<?define UpgradeCode20="ABCDEFGH-AAAA-BBBB-CCCC-DDDDDDDDDDDD"?>
<?define UpgradeCode21="12345678-1111-2222-3333-444444444444"?>

<?if $(var.ProductVersion)=2.0.0.0?>
   <?define ResourcesUpgradeCode="$(var.UpgradeCode20)"?>
<?endif?>
```

but this code return error. it means $(var.ProductVersion)=2.0.0.0 is not true.

```
error CNDL0150: Undefined preprocessor variable '$(var.ResourcesUpgradeCode)'.
```

I tried many times but nothing works.

It is what I tried.

```
<?if $(var.ProductVersion)="2.0.0.0"?>
<?if "$(var.ProductVersion)"="2.0.0.0"?>
<?if "$(var.ProductVersion)"=2.0.0.0?>
<?if $(var.ProductVersion)="2.0.0.0"?>
<?if !(wix.ProductVersion)="2.0.0.0"?>
<?if !(wix.ProductVersion)=2.0.0.0?>
```

and I tried define new variable and compare also return same error.

```
<?define CompareVersion20="2.0.0.0"?>
<?if $(var.ProductVersion)=$(var.CompareVersion20)?>
```

i think !(wix.ProductVersion) maybe cannot use if compare.
because this value is surely 2.0.0.0 but nothing cannot compare normally.

How can I compare !(wix.ProductVersion)=2.0.0.0 normally?
Or let me know other way to use UpgradeCode for each !(wix.ProductVersion).